# Why Cloudera's Impala is still "incubating"?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

We are using Impala in my company and we have used it in my previous one without 
problems.

Is there something affecting possible production use (for example, it breaks under heavy usage, or memory leaks possible, or concurrent access is not recommended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from http://incubator.apache.org/:

> The Apache Incubator has two primary goals:
>
> - Ensure all donations are in accordance with the ASF legal standards
> - Develop new communities that adhere to our guiding principles

According to the above, the Incubator doesn't have to do anything with performance or stability, but rather attracting an active, diverse community to a given project and reviewing the licenses involved.